# What is wrong with this code, in special with file?

Tags: c, file, stdio

> Implement an algorithm that reads a mathematical expression from the
>   standard input and writes to Standard output if the expression is
>   correctly bracketed.

I made the code but I do not know if it's okay how I used the file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *citire, *scriere; 
char expr[100];
int fe=0,i;


citire = fopen("in.txt", "rb");
scriere = fopen("out.txt", "wb");
fscanf(citire, "%s", &expr);

//input
i = 0;
while (expr[i] != '\0')        
{
    if (expr[i] == '(')
    {
        fe++;
    }
    else if (expr[i] == ')')
    {
        fe--;
        if (fe < 0) 
            break;
    }
    i++;
}
//output
if (fe == 0)
{
    fprintf(scriere, "DA\n");
}
else          
{
    fprintf(scriere, "NU\n");
}
fclose(citire);
fclose(scriere);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work or not?

Comment: The requirement mentions "standard input" (keyboard) and standard output (screen), so there is no need to use files here. The usage of files looks OK, apart from the missing error checks,

Comment: **not working**

Comment: Please read this: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "*reads [...] from the standard input and writes to Standard output*" it doesn't. It reads and writes from/to two specific files "directly".

Comment: you have to mention error we r not compiler to parse the code.. :)

Comment: Indeed, in the requirement does not write, but the teacher wants it

Comment: @AlinaCristinaCiocan then you should mention this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To read/write from Standard In-/Output replace this

```
citire = fopen("in.txt", "rb");
scriere = fopen("out.txt", "wb");
```

by this

```
citire = stdin;
scriere = stdout;
```

and drop the two calls to `fclose()`.

Then call the  program like this

```
./a.out <in.txt >out.txt
```

---

Alternatively you could drop the `FILE*` variables at all and switch from using the general `f*()` functions to using the Standard-I/O related versions:

- `fscanf()` --> `scanf()`
- `fprinf()` --> `printf()`

Comment: Thank you very much